# Can't access a 3d array in a struct defined in my .h file

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct

I have a struct in my main.h but when I try to allocate memory for the 3D array in the struct, I get the following compiler error.

```
    'text' has no member named 'list'
```

Now, I only get this for the 3D array the the other variables in the struct.

main.h

```
#define MAX_WORD 100

typedef struct textTag {
   char name[100];
   char  ***list;
   int words;
}text;
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "main.h"

void createArray(FILE *file, text *checkTexts, int fileCount,  int size){
   int i, n, wordCount, sections, rest;
   FILE *textFile;
   text localText;
   char fileName[MAX_WORD + 30];

   readFileNames(file, checkTexts);

   for(i = 0; i < fileCount; i++){
      localText = checkTexts[i];

      strcpy(fileName, "./testFolder/");
      strcat(fileName, checkTexts[i].name);
      openFile(&textFile, fileName);

      checkTexts[i].words = countWords(textFile);

      sections = (wordCount / size);
      rest = wordCount % size;
      checkTexts[i].list = malloc(sections * sizeof(char **)); //Compile error here

      for(n = 0; n < sections; n++){
         checkTexts[i].list[n] = malloc(size * sizeof(char *)); //Compile error here
      }

      checkTexts[i].list[sections] = malloc(rest * sizeof(char*)); //Compile error here

      readFileContent(textFile,checkTexts[i].list, size); //Compile error here

   }

}
```

Comment: Please include the compile errors

Comment: You mentioned only compiler error but didn't mention the exact error you received. You need to mention it.

Comment: The compiler says main.c:170:20: error: 'text' has no member named 'list'

Comment: Is the snippet for defining the struct all that is in the main.h file? If not, can you show the entire file? Your code compiles fine under gcc 4.5 but I defined text inline with the source file.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Commenting out lines with undefined functions and defining MAX_WORD, `gcc -W -c main.c` only warns about possible uninitialized use of `wordCount`.

Comment: the only other thing in main.h is #define MAX_WORD 100

I am compiling with Cygwin gcc4-core version 4.5.3-3 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Fixed the problem.

It was a stupid mistake be myself, where I had accidently opened the wrong main.h file, so I was editing a file for another project, so the struct I was using did indeed not have en variable called list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the comment.

Fixed the problem

It was a stupid mistake be my self, where i had accidently opened the wrong main.h file, so I was editing a file for an other project, so the struct i was using did indeed not have en member list.

But thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. `checkTexts` could be uninitialized - you could handle this with `assert()` from `assert.h`
2. Try [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/s/ddd/) to view your pointers during execution. This is one of the best ways to see what's going wrong.

Maybe this could help too:
http://c-faq.com/aryptr/
Especially 6.2, 6.3, 6.8.

Comment: Wait, where do you get your info. I have been trying to track down the source of excessive casting of malloc return values, it is rampant in homework questions on this site and usually a cause of problems.

Comment: Which problems are caused by typecasts? By casting them, you can sometimes track down errors more easily since type missmatches are reported and if you are experiencing problems you should double-check your assignments.

Comment: Well for one thing if you forget to include stdlib.h it means that malloc will return int instead of void*, that causes problems where sizeof(int) != sizeof(void*). A cast will prevent the compiler warning you of this.

Comment: In my opinion, not including stdlib is even worse. If you are using functions, you should make sure using the right declaration. This is just a matter of care. Both ways may cause problems so I edited my post ;).

Comment: I agree that not including stdlib is worse. But I have seen many questions lately where people needlessly cast malloc return value into something wrong.